# Not to allow user to change values in a link

Tags: php, html

I am emailing a link to users that is: (I am using html, php)

http://meetings.php?id=3&meetingname=change+2-actionitem&username=meeting.secretary%40alnnovative.com

When users open the link, they can change the user name from the link. Is there a way that I could restrict the users from changing it??

Comment: encode all these with your custom encoder function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that link points to your applications that you are developing, then you could encrypt the username in the link, and then decrypt it back while accessing it. so that the user would not be able to change the value.